# How to add a Child in a Child Data Firebase Realtime Database?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

I want to add a image in cover image filed how to do it?

Comment: upload image on firebase storage and insert the image url in the coverimage .

Comment: Can u show me how to do that?

Comment: `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("/PostAD/105122088625438796101/-MC6XJI5l-K-YB-7RkB8/CoverImage").setValue("a image")`?